# How to use some of bootstrap's mobile first classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble understanding bootstrap 4's mobile first behavior. I have always designed for desktops first and moved down from there.

Text centering is one such place where I don't know how to proceed.

For example, I want a paragraph to be centered on screens smaller than 768px.

So I looked up the documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/ and found out the class `text-md-center` and thought this is what I need. It centers text on medium width screens which are not larger than 768px.

However on using it did the opposite of what I thought - It centered the text for screen size larger than 768px.

I am assuming this is what is called 'mobile first'. Is this not mean for desktop first design? How do I center text only on smaller width devices?

Comment: Have you tried `text-sm-center` class?

Comment: @tcj `text-sm-center` centers for sizes greater than 576px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply 2 classes to your paragraph: `text-center` and `text-md-left`.

`text-center` means that the text is centred by default, then `text-md-left` means it is left-aligned on screens 768px wide and greater.

Answer (score 0):

Never been a fan of frontend frameworks such as Twitter Bootstrap.

Anyway, this is basically what it does under the hood

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .text-md-center {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

So you could add your own class like this.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .mobile-text-center-md {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Just an example anyway. Then use the `.mobile-text-center-md` class to center text on devices, less than `768px` wide.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking for a bootstrap way to do this without additional media queries.

Comment: I think you need to think about it the other way around. Add `text-align: center` for all text. Then add `text-md-left`, the `left` class will override the center one.